# Change ImageMagick policy on a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, imagemagick, dockerfile

There seems to have been a change recently on ImageMagick which breaks conversion from pdf to png. My investigation let me to the policy.xml file and this line:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

which needs to be changed to this

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

(Note: I didn't have this problem before).

I am able to change that on my personal machine but now I need to change it on a docker container configured through a Dockerfile. How can I do that?

I have tried something using environment variables without success. You can see my dockerfile here:

https://github.com/VivianePons/public-notebooks

Thank you for your help

Comment: You may issue a COPY command to put `policy.xml` in the right place. Or you may `RUN sed ...` on `policy.xml`.

Comment: Indeed, the copy worked, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Runtime bind mount

At runtime (`docker run`), use a [bind mounted volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to overwrite the `policy.xml` inside the container.

A good, straightforward example of doing this can be found in the [How to use this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) section of the official Nginx image on Docker Hub.

`docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx`

Here, the `-v` flag is your bind mount. `-v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html` says "replace `/usr/share/nginx/html` in the container with the contents of `/some/content` on my host. The end result for the user -- if `/some/content` has an index.html or other default home page as determined in the nginx.conf of the container, Nginx will require no configuration changes because the default Nginx configuration is already looking for index.html at that file system location.

**NOTE**: Bind mounting isn't additive. The directory on the image will be entirely replaced by whats being mounted.

### Dockerfile COPY

Or at build time (`docker build`) use [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in your Dockerfile to bake your updated `policy.xml` right into the container, no bind mounting required.

`COPY ./path/to/policy.xml /path/in/docker/image/policy.xml`

Comment: The question does not say so explicitly, but by looking at the GitHub repo it is clear that the goal is to have a Docker image compatible with MyBinder.org. Runtime bind mounts are not available in this setting.

Comment: Good find, important detail.

Answer (score 14):

This change to your Dockerfile works

```
ARG imagemagic_config=/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

RUN if [ -f $imagemagic_config ] ; then sed -i 's/<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" \/>/<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" \/>/g' $imagemagic_config ; else echo did not see file $imagemagic_config ; fi
```

Comment: If I run this manually, it works. But within a Dockerfile I get `[[: not found` because `[[` is a bash built-in and `RUN` does not seem to execute it via an actual bash.

Comment: @LenaSchimmel  try a single [ instead of [[